# Writing, deploying, installing command line tool written in shell

Tags: linux, macos, shell, command-line

*It's just one of those days...*
I want to create a shell script (naive version could be a simple `alias`), but I want to make it the good way from the bottom up. Writing script itself isn't a problem at all, but since it's possible a couple of other people would like to use this script as well I want to make it accessible and maintainable as well. That's why I have two questions:

1. Are there any guides regarding structure of the repository with shell script inside? I mean, some conventions that, for example, we put a script in some directory, manpage, should I split it into multiple files etc.
2. How to make this script be accessible to other people? I know that if we want to install command line tool, we move it to `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, but what with docs or some dependencies?

There are a lot of tutorials regarding writing command line tools in Ruby or Python with some templates how to manage everything, but I haven't found anything about writing a command line tool as a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you would follow the conventions in `man hier` for the distribution. A shell script would be treated the same as a binary file.